# can i upload files and some text fields in the same form

Tags: jsf, file-upload

I'm using JSF, CDI. Can i upload file and some text fields in the same form?

```
<h:form>
<h:inputText value="#{mybean.discription}" />
<p:fileUpload value="#{mybean.file}" mode="simple"/> //Or <h:inputFile value="#{mybean.file}"/> if using jsf2.2
<h:commandButton action="#{mybean.submit}" value="Submit"/>
</h:form>
```

I saw a lot of tutorials about uploading file, but in those tutorials only use single component to upload file.
I tried to do but i didn't.
Can you give me an answer? Thanks

Comment: yes you can upload file and have some text fields as well in the same form

Comment: as you say @Ashish Chopra, i did wrong in some where?

Comment: Check the primefaces doc for p:fileupload the pdf, not the showcase

Answer (score 0):

I done. I forgot `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:inputText value="#{mybean.discription}" />
    <p:fileUpload value="#{mybean.file}" mode="simple" />
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{mybean.submit}" />
</h:form>
```